# Can't add values of 4D variable to new array

Tags: python, plot, interpolation, netcdf

I have variable temperature -> thetao(time, depth, lon, lat) later on I want to make plot of interpolations over time.

Dataset is netcdf and I have accessed it using xarray.

I'm having trouble with getting the values of temperatures to new array, I'm stuck and don't know how.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

I managed to get matrix of coordinates with as I need it for griddata as fuction of griddata is griddata(points, values, request):

```
`points[]
for i in range(len(depth)):
    for j in range(len(lon)):
        for k in range(len(lat)):
            points.append((depth[i],lon[j],lat[k]))
```

`
I assume that in order to get interpolations over time I'll have to loop over time, but for now I'm stuck :)